# dictionary not created properly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, dictionary, nsdictionary

i am creating a nsdictionary in app using below code.

```
  NSDictionary *allImportDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            [NSNumber numberWithInt:containerId], @"containerId",
                                 [NSNumber numberWithInt:docTypeId], @"docTypeId",filextension, @"fileExt",metaDataFiellds, @"metaDataFields",[NSNumber numberWithInt:tmpRepoId], @"repositoryId",[NSNumber numberWithInt:1], @"pagesCount",
                                 tmpSessionID, @"sessionId", fileName, @"title",guid, @"tmpFileName",[NSNumber numberWithInt:tmpUserID], @"userId",
                            nil];
```

but it create dictionary as below

Printing description of allImportDict:

```
{
    containerId = 2;
    docTypeId = 1;
}
```

Please guide me why it does not include all keys as most of keys are missing ?

Comment: check your `filextension, @"fileExt"`

Comment: what is the issue with that ?

Comment: `filextension` seems to be `nil`, and then stop the construction of the dictionary.

Comment: @iOSGuy - filextension is nil or empty, thats the reason all other other keys are not added

Comment: if it's nil then i should get a crash i guess

Comment: If you use short syntax: = @{@"containerId":[NSNumber numberWithInt:containerId], andSo On}, it will crash. But with `initWithObjectsAndKeys:` it will stop at the first nil value. "That's why" you put at the end yourself `nil`.

Comment: @iOSGuy - if you a doubt add the static data and check

Answer (score 0):

your NSDictionary "fileExt" parameter contain "nil" value.Plz, update it and check.

Answer (score 0):

I just added validation to values and replaced `NSDictionary` with `NSMutableDictionary`. Any null value can break your code. You can just copy paste the following code.

```
NSMutableDictionary *allImportDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    if(containerId) {
        [allImportDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:containerId] forKey:@"containerId"];
    }

    if(docTypeId) {
        [allImportDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:docTypeId] forKey:@"docTypeId"];
    }

    if([self canUseString:filextension]) {
        [allImportDict setObject:filextension forKey:@"fileExt"];
    }

    if([self canUseString:metaDataFiellds]) {
        [allImportDict setObject:metaDataFiellds forKey:@"metaDataFiellds"];
    }

    if(tmpRepoId) {
        [allImportDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:tmpRepoId] forKey:@"tmpRepoId"];
    }

    [allImportDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:@"pagesCount"];

    if([self canUseString:tmpSessionID]) {
        [allImportDict setObject:tmpSessionID forKey:@"sessionId"];
    }

    if([self canUseString:fileName]) {
        [allImportDict setObject:fileName forKey:@"fileName"];
    }

    if([self canUseString:guid]) {
        [allImportDict setObject:guid forKey:@"guid"];
    }

    if(tmpUserID) {
        [allImportDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:tmpUserID] forKey:@"userId"];
    }

    NSLog(@"allImportDict: %@", allImportDict);
```